# Disguising .pdf extension using .htaccess avoiding cycling

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdf

I have a little bit stupid necessity to disguise links to PDF files as PHP files with the PDF filename as a parameter.

Something like:

1. Client requests xxxx.pdf file.
2. Server receives request but instead of returning xxxx.pdf goes to yyyy.php or whatever extension.
3. yyyy.php has an iframe in which the PDF file is loaded.

The thing is that I managed to do point 2. but when I try to do point 3. it either cycles or doesn't locate the file.

I was thinking of having a custom extension to "simulate" another file in order to not cycle but it's still cycling.

I have the following .htaccess:

```
AddType application/pdf         .view
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.pdf$         yyyy.php?filename=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.view$        $1.pdf [L]
```

The thing is that it cycles and I get nowhere.

I am not really good with .htaccess, so where am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easier to just redirect when I detect a .pdf extension.

So I basically did this:

1. .htaccess detects a PDF extension and redirects to a php file passing the filename without extension as a parameter.
2. The php file uses the filename and renders the PDF using `header` and `readfile` to avoid conflicts with .htaccess.

Something like that:

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule     ^(.*)\.pdf$     /pdfreader/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
RewriteRule     ^pdfreader/(.*)?$           pdfreader.php?file=$1 [L,NC]
```

pdfreader.php

```
$file = $_GET["file"].".pdf";

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add something to prevent the referer for `yyyy.php` from getting rewritten *back* to the php file. Add this before your yyyy.php rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yyyy\.php
```

Note that referers can be forged, so this is one way people will be able to bypass the yyyy.php file.

Comment: Didn't work for me, kept cycling, I did find an easier solution. I am going to publish it.